# Recovering Python modules

Tags: python, module

I have accidentally deleted my Python modules such as the random and turtle module from a Windows 7 machine. I am unsure on how to reinstall them.

Comment: What Python modules? What system? What?

Comment: I am runnig python on windows 7 and I accidently deleted the modules that include random and the turtle function.

Comment: i'd go with reinstalling python

Comment: Is that the only way as I encountered many problems when I downloaded it the first time.

Comment: depends on which modules have you lost. You may install python in virtual machine and copy all the missing files from there, i guess, without breaking your current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go to the settings in there and if there is no way of finding them then you can go onto the python website and reinstall them from there :-)

Answer (score 1):

you will have to uninstall and download python again but if you save the files to a secure area you will still have them.

Comment: Please read earlier comment and you will see why i don't want to reinstall python.